# Convert Date Range into Days with Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to populate values base on a date range and static value, my table looks like this

```
Name |   Start Date | End Date |   Hrs
Joe      6/20/2017    6/22/2017     3
Michael  6/18/2017    6/21/2017     3
```

what I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
Name 6/18/2017 6/19/2017 6/20/2017 6/21/2017 6/22/2017
Joe     0         0         3         3          3
Michael 3         3         3         3          0
```

My data is on a table that is dynamically updated as a pivot table.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Macros, you could perform the following:

Note: This assumes that you have a ready made 'output table' with all the dates as a header and the names in the same row numbers.

1. Loop through your source data row by row, each time storing the `Start
   Date`, `End Date` and `Hrs` as a variable.
2. Follow this up with a search to identify in the header of the 'output table' the corresponding `Start Date`.
3. Then proceed to fill up the cells with the `Hrs` associated with the name until the `End Date`.

Each time you update your pivot table, you'll just need to re-run the macro again assuming that the cell references of the source table and output table do not change!

Good luck!